# Extract html element with python beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to learn web-scraping and want to extract the price **$46.00-$50.00** from the below HTML blob using python

```
<div class="organic-gallery-offer-section__price">
    <p class="elements-offer-price-normal medium" data-e2e-name="price@@normal" title="$46.00-$50.00"><span class="elements-offer-price-normal__price">$46.00-$50.00</span><span class="elements-offer-price-normal__unit">/ Piece</span></p>
    <p class="element-offer-minorder-normal medium" data-e2e-name="minOrder"><span class="element-offer-minorder-normal__value">2 Pieces</span><span class="element-offer-minorder-normal__suffix">(Min Order)</span></p>
</div>]
```

So far the code I have written which is not working out is

```
item.findAll("div",{"class":"elements-offer-price-normal medium"})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways how you can extract the desired text, for example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''
<div class="organic-gallery-offer-section__price">
    <p class="elements-offer-price-normal medium" data-e2e-name="price@@normal" title="$46.00-$50.00"><span class="elements-offer-price-normal__price">$46.00-$50.00</span><span class="elements-offer-price-normal__unit">/ Piece</span></p>
    <p class="element-offer-minorder-normal medium" data-e2e-name="minOrder"><span class="element-offer-minorder-normal__value">2 Pieces</span><span class="element-offer-minorder-normal__suffix">(Min Order)</span></p>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('span', class_="elements-offer-price-normal__price").text)
```

Prints:

```
$46.00-$50.00
```

---

Or: Use CSS selector:

```
print(soup.select_one('div.organic-gallery-offer-section__price span').text)
```